# peek operation in stack using javascript

Tags: javascript, stack

How can I get the first element from my stack
here is my code

```
var stack = [];
stack.push(id1);
stack.push(id2);
```

I know there is something like peek in java. Is there any similar method in JS using which i can get the topmost element?

Comment: I don't think. Though you can either define yourself using `Array.prototype.peek = fn(){..}` or use custom function which would do `return arr[arr.length - 1]`

Comment: Ỳou mean like using `stack[0]`?

Comment: @AndrewLi isn't `arr[arr.length -1]` better than doing 2 operation (*pop and push*)

Comment: @Rajesh wouldn't that give the last element?

Comment: If using slice is okay? what is wrong with `unshift()`

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal Isn't that what `peek` does?

Comment: @Rajesh I am not sure about `peek` but the question reads first element so I asked. :)

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal In stack, first element is the last 1 you pushed. Consider a stack of books. Which is the first book on top. Also your suggestion is correct about `unshift`. Also about `peek`, what would you do to read name of book on top? You would read it without moving it.

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks, now I get it. but then how is `unshift()` okay shouldn't it be `pop()`? but I think OP just wants to read and not modify his stack. so `arr[arr.length - 1]` is better suited.

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal My bad. Used a bad example to check it and got confused. Also `pop` is not ideal as it will remove last element and return it to you.

Comment: Unable to understand why not to use `stack[0]`?

Comment: `stack[0]` returns the item at the *bottom* of the stack. `peek()` is meant to return the item on *top* of the stack. A peek function should return the last item you pushed to the stack, which will be at the end of the array.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

To check the topmost element unfortunately you must explicitly index it

```
var top = stack[stack.length-1];
```

the syntax `stack[-1]` (that would work in Python) doesn't work: negative indexes are valid only as parameters to `slice` call.

```
// The same as stack[stack.length-1], just slower and NOT idiomatic
var top = stack.slice(-1)[0];
```

To **extract** an element there is however `pop`:

```
// Add two top-most elements of the stack
var a = stack.pop();
var b = stack.pop();
stack.push(a + b);
```

Comment: Chrome has `.getLast()` but obviously this is only on Chrome.

Comment: but Why not to use `stack[0]`?

Comment: @PardeepJain: because `push` and `pop` work on the last element of the array. Using `splice` to insert and removing elements from the beginning would make the two operations `O(n)` instead of `O(1)` (this is not strictly necessary as one could design a ring-buffer based array supporting amortized `O(1)` insertion at both ends and with `O(1)` removal at both ends and indexing, but it's not what common implementations do).

Comment: thanks for comment but `stack[0]` will stay same right?

Comment: @PardeepJain: `stack[0]` is the first element... if you want to remove it from the array either you make a loop or you write `stack.splice(0, 1)`. The latter however is in most implementations still a loop done by the Javascript runtime and therefore removing the first element requires `O(n)` time.

Comment: Oh like that, yes got it. Thanks @6502 for information

Comment: @RozzA, `getLast` isn't a thing. I assume you were either using a mixin or perhaps it existed at one point but no longer.

Comment: @6502 - Sorry if this is a noob question, but what did you mean "NOT Idiomatic"?

Comment: @Krishnabm: it's not something you will find often in Javascript code... it's not a common pattern of this language. A javascript programmer would have to think understand what such an expression does... it's "weird".

Answer (score 9):

Edited 2022:

Now you can just use `stack.at(-1)`

---

If you just need one edge of your stack (head or tail is not matter) use it reversed:

I mean :

`peek()` become `array[0]`,
`unshift(v)` become `push()`
`shift()` become `pop()`

some code:

```js
class Stack{
  constructor(... args ){
    this.store = [... args.reverse()];
  }
  peek(){
    return this.store[0];
  }
  push(value){
    return this.store.unshift(value);
  }
  pop(){
   return this.store.shift();
  }
}

const stack = new Stack(1,2,3);
stack.push(4);
console.log(stack.peek());
stack.pop();
console.log(stack.peek())
```

or shorter

```js
function Stack(...rest){
  var store = [... rest.reverse() ];
  return {
    push:(v)=> store.unshift(v) ,
    pop : _ => store.shift(),
    peek: _ => store[0]
    }
  }
  
var stack = Stack(1,2,3);
console.log(stack.peek());
stack.push(4);
console.log(stack.peek());
stack.pop(), stack.pop();
console.log(stack.peek());
```

Comment: i get it, but plz don't try to confuse ppl

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. looking at array on reverse order is a common way to solve various problems.

Comment: This is a terrible solution for any kind of stack/queue. Manipulating the end of an array is O(1), while manipulating the start of an array is O(n). So to gain a less clumsy `peek` you sacrifice the efficiency of the most common operations on a queue/stack -- `push` and `pop`.

Comment: JS is not a real `array` is HASH or LINKING LIST

Comment: @perymimon That is not true. It depends on the implementation. Modern JS engines are smart enough to use a native backing array when the object is initialized and updated strictly like an array. For example, see [Elements kinds in V8](https://v8.dev/blog/elements-kinds). Even sparse arrays are supported these days very efficiently.

Comment: Making a copy of the handed-in `...rest` arguments array is a good intention, but not necessary. The parameters array is created internally during the call, so no-one can reference this array and there is no need to copy it before modification. So just use `var store = rest.reverse()`.

Comment: What are the underscores at `pop` and `peek` are supposed to do? `_` is a legal variable/parameter name, so it looks as though both methods receive a parameter that is ignored. What you really want to express is an empty parameter list, `()`.  Instead, you can leave out the parenthesis around `push`'s parameter `v`.

Comment: @YetAnotherFrank `_` is a just cleaner and short way to tell that I'm not using the parameter.  one latter instead of two . and for me visualize, it look much cleaner

Comment: @perymimon My point is that these methods do not _have_ any parameter to ignore.

Answer (score 5):

```js
var stack = [];
stack.push("id1");
stack.push("id2");
console.log(stack[stack.length-1]); // the top element
console.log(stack.length); //size
```

Answer (score 2):

I just want to add here the .at prototype function.
Documentation is found here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at

So, to get the peek is as simple as:

```
[array].at(-1);
```

Example:

```
const stack = [];
stack.push("sample1");
stack.push("sample2");

console.log(stack.at(-1)) // sample2
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var stackArr = [1,2,3,4];

console.log(stackArr[stackArr.length-1]);
//expected output is 4;
```

Answer (score -3):

```js
        var stack = [];
        stack.push("id1");
        stack.push("id2");
        var topObj = stack[0]
       console.log(topObj)
```

Comment: `stack[0]` is the *bottom* value on the stack